# How to insert data in a column from another column of another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, rdbms

I have a table `EMP` that looks like this

```
EID || ENAME || ESAL || LOC
------------------------------------------------------------ 
1111 || David Rockwell || 50000 || - 
2222 || Michael Bubey || 33000 || - 
3333 || Samuel Lukas || 35000 || - 
5555 || Mike Pribley || 35000 || -
```

I have another table `DEPT` that looks like this

```
DEPT_ID ||   DNAME  ||  LOCATION
-----------------------------------------------
1111          ||   ABC        ||    USA
2222         || DEF        || Japan
3333         || GHI         || UK
4444         || JKL         ||Brazil
5555         || LMO        || India
```

My aim is to insert the values of `dept.LOCATION` into `emp.LOC`

NOTE:

1. The insertion should be such that the `emp.loc=dept.LOCATION`
   where `dept.dept_id=emp_eid`
2. There are no constraints in any of the tables. (You are free to add in your solution)

**RESULT**

```
EID  ||     ENAME                    || ESAL   ||   LOC 
------------------------------------------------------------
1111 ||  David Rockwell  || 50000 ||      USA 
2222 || Michael Bubey   || 33000 ||   JAPAN 
3333 || Samuel Lukas      || 35000 ||     UK 
5555 || Mike Pribley         || 35000 ||      India
```

Thank you for your support.

Comment: This is a violation of database normalization principles. You shouldn't duplicate the location information in two tables, then you have to do extra work to keep them in sync all the time.